# RoR - Where to put/initialize constant for a lib module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 application, I have a module in the lib/ folder. The module requires a constant variable, which is a big dictionary loaded from a data file. Since the dictionary won't change over the course of the application and its time consuming to reload this data file everytime a method from the module is called, I want to create a constant which holds the dictionary that can be accessed by the module in the lib.

#### lib/my_module:

```
module My_Module
   def do_something(x)
      y = CONSTANTVAR[x]
      ...
   end
end
```

to initialize the constant, I have to load a file:

```
file = File.new('dataFile.dat','r') #I'm not sure where to put this data file
file.each_line { |line|
             lineInfo = line.split
             CONSTANTVAR[line[0]] = line[1] }
file.close
```

Where is the standard place to initialize variables that can be accessed by modules in the lib folder (this is the only place I will be accessing the variable)?

Also, the module loads a data file, is it standard to put data files in the lib/ folder as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look on how it is done here: https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery

It is a lib for generating words and it uses dictionaries. They are saved in : /lib/forgery/dictionary/*

So, save you dictionary on /lib/module-name/dictionaries/DATA.dat

And you can initialise your variable in config/initialisers/module-name.rb

Answer (score 0):

I should put my, say, init_dictionary.rb in config/initializers. I think it's the better place for your requirement.